# Simple NodeJS socketIO server throws error

Tags: node.js

Trying to debug this simple NodeJS socketIO server.

I keep getting the following error message on launch. I can't see anything wrong with the code.

Can anyone help?

> TypeError: listener must be a function
>       at TypeError ()
>       at Namespace.EventEmitter.addListener (events.js:130:11)
>       at Server.(anonymous function) [as on] (/Users/foo/bin/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:364:16)
>       at Object. (/Users/foo/bin/foo.js:11:4)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>       at startup (node.js:119:16)*

```
var app = require("express");
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

io.on("connection", handleClient);


var handleClient = function (socket) {
    // we've got a client connection

    socket.emit("tweet", {user: "nodesource", text: "Hello, world!"});
};

app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing some parens:

```
var app = require('express')();
```

Answer (score 2):

you have forgotten to take an instance of express. I hope my below example will help you.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

io.on("connection", handleClient);


var handleClient = function (socket) {
    // we've got a client connection

    socket.emit("tweet", {user: "nodesource", text: "Hello, world!"});
};

app.listen(8080);
```